# I have 20k++ data from firebase that slows my web, how do I make it more efficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an analytics web for a company using react.js + firebase, and we currently have like 20k data. So the current website flows are like this:

1. Admin opens the website, React.js fetches the data from the firebase.
2. Once the data is fetched, we store it into an array and past it down to another component
3. Since we have like 20k data++, this progress significantly slows down the web.

How can I improve this?

Things I notice:

- Changing the data structure, however since it takes too much time, I need to think about other solutions, which is paginating the data from the firebase so it doesn't load 20k data in one go.

Comment: Hey @edward-tanoto , Can you please let me know how's the payment with 20k data? 
And are you fetching this for all users(admins) ? Moreover each time you refresh I think increases reads in firestore. How you are managing it?

Comment: rich corporate lol @profiile_samir

Answer (score 1):

1. Just get enough data. Don't need to fetch 20K data at one time. That's why almost all tables use pagination or infinite scroll.
2. Use efficient methods to manipulate the data. For example, `Object.freeze` can be used to make arrays not reactive.

Also you can display just required parts. For example, use lazy components or sth like that.

Comment: Lazy components sounds cool, i'll try it out, thanks! @sirius